# reload ioctl on test_map failed: No such device

Tags: linux, драйвер, kernel

Взял основу драйвера из статьи на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106702/)
Сам ввод/вывод работает.
Но когда делаю:

```
dmsetup create test_map --table '0 16 linear /dev/test 0'
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
reload ioctl on test_map failed: No such device
```

Как я понял, я что-то не реализовал из **file_operations**

Подскажите, что конкретно.

Сейчас file_operations выглядит следующим образом:

```
static struct file_operations fops =
 {
  .read = device_read,
  .write = device_write,
  .open = device_open,
  .release = device_release,
  .unlocked_ioctl = my_ioctl,
  .owner = THIS_MODULE
 };
```

Comment: Посмотрите на вывод setrace при вызове dmsetup create test_map --table '0 16 linear /dev/test 0' думаю там вы найдете вызов, на котором произошел фейл